# div element is mysteriously disappearing at certain offsets

Tags: css

I'm not a designer and only know enough CSS to get by, so I'll be very impressed by anyone who can help me out.

I have a div that is absolutely positioned, and is 100% (probably irrelevant) of its parent div in height. It has a width of just 1px. It's a cursor for a music player.

The problem is, depending on the value I set for 'left', I can only sometimes see the div. It seems to follow a pattern, i.e. I can see the cursor for about 10 or 15 pixels and then it disappears for 1 or 2. The computed with also shows up as 0.992px instead of 1px, even though I directly set the width to be 1px.

```
#cursor {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: add a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) your information is not sufficient

Comment: But how are we supposed to help if you didn't provide any code?

Comment: I explained the relevant pieces of the problem, I'm not sure it deserves a downvote. You can just ask.

Comment: Code, please. How can we help you without code? Provide code, I'll upvote you.

Comment: *"..is 100% of its parent div.."* and *"It has a width of just 1px."* Those two sentences are confusing.. or is it just me?

Comment: question edited. 100% of the height, 1px width. Good catch

Comment: I think you mean, 100% height of its parent div ? in which case you need to make it by making top:0px and bottom:0px, not the height 100%, as it is absolute positioned.
Whenever i tried to create such cursors i tried to make the width as 0px and make the border-left or border right as 1 or 2px and it always worked for me. Could you please try that ?

Comment: This is a great alternate solution, and it works. I upvoted the response, but I'm still curious as to why I observed this behavior when using 1px width. Thanks allupaku

Comment: I tried to reproduce your use-case. It seems just fine to me. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/4CT9U/1/

Comment: @RobertKotcher is the computed width always .992px, or only in those circumstances when it's invisible?

Comment: @MrLister it is always this width. I had some comments above to provide code, so if there is anything else that might be necessary to solving this I can add it in. Thanks!

Comment: @RobertKotcher The code doesn't match the text in your question (which says 1px, and the code says 2px) but the more important question is, are you sure you're viewing the page at a zoom factor of 100%?

Comment: @MrLister Thanks yes I copy/pasted while I was debugging. The code matches now. And yes, the zoom is 100%.